# VSCode PORTS Tab missing in WSL2

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, port, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am using VSCode with WSL2 on Windows 11. On Linux I am used to have a `PORTS` tab close to the `TERMINAL` tab, but here it is missing.

When I start a Docker container with a forwarded port (here: JupyterLab with port 8888 exposed and forwarded) I can not see it there. Furthermore when starting JupyterLab in the container and clicking on the link I get an error.

The image below shows the missing `PORTS` Tab.

[image]

When using "Attach Visual Studio Code" to the attach VSCode to the running Docker container the new window being attached to the container will have the `PORTS` tab.

[image]

Why is the `PORTS` tab missing in VSCode with WSL2? Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a different version installed. Make sure you have at least version 1.82, see [release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_82#_workbench).

Alternatively, you may have hidden it (through right click -> Hide). There does not appear to be a corresponding setting in vscode's `settings.json`, but you can show it again through right-click on the side bar:

[image]